Adjust plot according to whether one or two of three checkboxes are selected
I have this app.

Individually checking "Show p-value levels" or "Show 95% confidence levels" works fine. However, when both are checked, I need the asterisks to be positioned above the error bars. At the moment, when both are checked, it looks like this:
Is there a way that I can write: If input A is checked but not input B then do this; if input B is checked but not A, do this; if both are checked then do this? (All of these options should happen regardless of whether input C is checked.)
My code:
cbPalette <- c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73") #color-blind friendly palette or "#CC79A7"?
 

fun_select_cat <- function(table, cat) {
  table %>% 
    filter(variable == cat)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(selectInput('cat','Select Category', c('Number of Enterprises','Assets','Costs','Net Revenues','Revenues')),
    checkboxInput("control_mean",label = "Show average for non-recipients", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("p_values",label = "Show p-value levels", value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput("error_bars",label = "Show 95% confidence intervals", value = FALSE),    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput('plot_overall'))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot_overall <- renderPlot({
    control_y = fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% pull(Control)
    Sig_height_y = fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% pull(Sig_height)
    Sig_y = fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% pull(Sig)
    new_est_y = fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% pull(new_est)
    
    fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = new_est, fill = Treatment)) +
      geom_col() + scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette) +
      guides(fill = FALSE) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(), expand = c(0,0)) +
      theme_classic() +
      scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=14,face="bold"),
            axis.text=element_text(size=12)) +
      {if(input$p_values) geom_text(aes(label = Sig_y), y = Sig_height_y)} +
      {if(input$p_values & table_2 |>
           filter(new_est == max(new_est)) |>
            ungroup() |>
            select(Sig) |>
      (\(.) all(!is.na(.)))()) expand_limits(y= c(0, new_est_y *1.05))} +
      {if(input$error_bars) geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= lower, ymax=higher), width= 0.25)} +
      {if(input$control_mean) annotate("text", x = 3.6, y = 1.078 * control_y, 
           label = "Control\nmean",
           colour = "#CC79A7",
           fontface =2,
           size = 4.5)} +
      {if(input$control_mean)expand_limits(x= c(1, length(levels(table_2$Treatment)) + 0.75))} +
      {if(input$control_mean) geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Control), linetype='dashed', col = '#CC79A7', size = 1.5)} +
      if(input$cat %in% c("Number of Enterprises", "Assets")
      ) {labs(title= input$cat, x = NULL, y = NULL)
      } else{labs(title = paste(input$cat, "(USD) for the last 30 days", sep =" "), x = NULL, y = NULL)}
     
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

dput(table_2)
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Long Term", 
"Short Term", "Lump Sum"), class = "factor"), variable = c("Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
"Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues"), Control = c(73.23, 
100036.59, 92636.84, 54533.59, 150207.24, 73.23, 100036.59, 92636.84, 
54533.59, 150207.24, 73.23, 100036.59, 92636.84, 54533.59, 150207.24
), Estimate = c(9.93, 36050.66, 32055.29, 28226.05, 61379.4, 
14.67, 29404.54, 71903.23, 35576.39, 107746.75, 3.39, 16441.81, 
8497.42, 14824.71, 23177.47), SE = c(3.96, 12589.11, 16478.13, 
12334.27, 24346.05, 3.92, 10977.68, 24360.84, 13382.81, 34895.03, 
3.57, 10029.27, 10462.44, 8143.69, 16080.92), Sig = c("�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
"�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
"�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
"�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
"�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", "�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097�\u0088\u0097", 
NA, NA, NA, "�\u0088\u0097", NA), new_est = c(83.16, 136087.25, 
124692.13, 82759.64, 211586.64, 87.9, 129441.13, 164540.07, 90109.98, 
257953.99, 76.62, 116478.4, 101134.26, 69358.3, 173384.71), lower = c(75.3984, 
111412.5944, 92394.9952, 58584.4708, 163868.382, 80.2168, 107924.8772, 
116792.8236, 63879.6724, 189559.7312, 69.6228, 96821.0308, 80627.8776, 
53396.6676, 141866.1068), higher = c(90.9216, 160761.9056, 156989.2648, 
106934.8092, 259304.898, 95.5832, 150957.3828, 212287.3164, 116340.2876, 
326348.2488, 83.6172, 136135.7692, 121640.6424, 85319.9324, 204903.3132
), Sig_height = c(87.318, 142891.6125, 130926.7365, 86897.622, 
222165.972, 92.295, 135913.1865, 172767.0735, 94615.479, 270851.6895, 
80.451, 122302.32, 106190.973, 72826.215, 182053.9455)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), groups = structure(list(
    variable = c("Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Number of Enterprises", 
    "Revenues"), .rows = structure(list(c(2L, 7L, 12L), c(3L, 
    8L, 13L), c(4L, 9L, 14L), c(1L, 6L, 11L), c(5L, 10L, 15L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))


As a first step I would suggest to refactor your plotting code and move all the if conditions for the conditional layers outside of the ggplot "pipeline". This makes it much easier to specify your conditions and to add your additional condition.
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("cat", "Select Category", c("Number of Enterprises", "Assets", "Costs", "Net Revenues", "Revenues")),
      checkboxInput("control_mean", label = "Show average for non-recipients", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("p_values", label = "Show p-value levels", value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput("error_bars", label = "Show 95% confidence intervals", value = FALSE),
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot_overall"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot_overall <- renderPlot({
    table_2_filtered <- fun_select_cat(table_2, input$cat) |> 
      ungroup()
    
    control_y <- table_2_filtered %>% pull(Control) |> unique()

    title <- if (input$cat %in% c("Number of Enterprises", "Assets")) {
      input$cat
    } else {
      paste(input$cat, "(USD) for the last 30 days", sep = " ")
    }
    layer_error <- if (input$error_bars) {
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = higher), width = 0.25)
    }
    layer_p <- if (input$p_values) {
      column_y_text <- if (input$error_bars) {
        "higher"
      } else {
        "new_est"
      }
      max_y_text <- table_2_filtered |> 
        filter(!is.na(Sig)) |> 
        pull(column_y_text) |> 
        max()
      
      list(
        geom_text(aes(label = Sig, y = 1.05 * .data[[column_y_text]]), na.rm = TRUE),
        if (!is.na(max_y_text)) expand_limits(y = c(0, max_y_text * 1.05))
      )
    }
    
    layer_control <- if (input$control_mean) {
      list(
        annotate("label",
          x = 3.6, y = control_y,
          label = "Control\nmean",
          colour = "#CC79A7",
          fontface = 2,
          size = 4.5,
          label.size = 0,
          fill = NA,
          vjust = 0
        ),
        geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Control), linetype = "dashed", col = "#CC79A7", size = 1.5),
        expand_limits(x = c(1, nlevels(table_2$Treatment) + 0.75))
      )
    }

    table_2_filtered |> 
      ggplot(aes(x = Treatment, y = new_est, fill = Treatment)) +
      geom_col() +
      scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette) +
      guides(fill = FALSE) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma(), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme_classic() +
      scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12)
      ) +
      layer_p +
      layer_error +
      layer_control +
      labs(title = title, x = NULL, y = NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)



This is so neat, thank you! Not only did you answer my question and solve my issue, but you have taught me a much cleaner way of organising my code that I will use from now on. Greatly appreciated!
